# How to set row Background color for WPF DataGrid Programmatically (WPF & C#) based on the value in the DataGrid

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, binding, wpftoolkit, wpfdatagrid

I have a WPF Datagrid binded with list of interface objects.
Consider, ClsEmployee class implements I_Employee interface with properties Empl_Id, Empl_Name, Department, Address and City_name.

List _emplList;

consider, _emplList has 10 items.

dgEmployeeGrid.ItemsSource = _emplList;

Question:
Now, if the user clicks on a button, then i should be able to read the City_name. Based on the City_name, i should be able to set the color (Color can be different for each row) for the rows dynamically through C# code.

Please help me how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a [ValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) that takes in a "value" of the appropriate type in the grid, and then bind the Background color of the row to that field with the ValueConverter in there to provide the [Color brush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970904.aspx) or whatever other kind of brush (that makes sense) that you'd like to put in there.

**EDIT**

Here is a Converter that converts a bool to a Brush color.  This class has two properties called "True" and "False" which we set a Brush to that will be used when the boolean value matches the property. The converter is one way and does not convert brushes back to boolean values.

**XAML to create instance of the Converter and set properties**

```
<cga:BoolToBrushConverter x:Key="trueIsGreen" 
    True="Green" 
    False="Red"/>
```

**C# Converter Code**

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(Brush))]
public class BoolToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public Brush True
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public Brush False
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
                          object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (targetType != typeof(Brush))
        {
            return null;
        }

        return ((bool) value) ? True : False;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
                              object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Example of binding value and convert to a field on an object that takes brushes**

```
<Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" 
       Fill="{Binding Path=Reviewer.IsMentor, Mode=OneWay, 
                      Converter={StaticResource trueIsGreen}}"/>
```

I'm assuming you are familiar with databinding in WPF and won't elaborate that aspect of the solution but when the `Reviewer.IsMentor` is true, the Converter will provide a "Green" brush (sent when the Converter was created) to the Fill property of the ellipse.

Comment: Hi Dave, I am quite new to WPF. Can you please provide some code?